# How to prove that $\varphi (1_A) = 1_{\prod_{i=1}^n (A/\mathfrak{a}_i)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Here is what I am trying to prove:

Let $A$ be a ring and  $\mathfrak{a}_1, \dots,\mathfrak{a}_n$ ideals of $A.$ Define a homomorphism $$\varphi : A \to \prod_{i=1}^n (A/\mathfrak{a}_i)$$ by the rule $$\varphi (x) = (x + \mathfrak{a}_1, \dots ,x + \mathfrak{a}_n )$$

Prove that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Here is my trial:

$\varphi (1_A) = (1_A + \mathfrak{a}_1, \dots ,1_A + \mathfrak{a}_n ),$

but I do not know why  $1_A + \mathfrak{a}_1 = \mathfrak{a}_1,$ does any ideal contains the multiplicative identity of the ring?if so, why?

Comment: If you know that $A \rightarrow A /\mathfrak{a}_i$ is a ring homomorphism, you can then use the universal property of products.

Comment: @DavidLui To each his own and all, but I think it's a bit ambitious to suggest a proof via universal property to somebody seeking help to verify a function is a ring homomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to be true in general that $1_A+\mathfrak a_1=\mathfrak a_1$. In fact you don't want this. You want to show (among other things) that $\varphi(1_A)$ is the *multiplicative* identity of the product ring, not the additive identity. What is the multiplicative identity of $\prod_{i=1}^n (A/\mathfrak a_i)$?

Comment: is it $(1_A + \mathfrak a_1 , \dots 1_A + \mathfrak a_n)$? maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. But be sure to verify for yourself that it satisfies the correct property for multiplicative identity!

Comment: Yeah, I am sure from this.

Comment: So there is nothing to prove here, it just follows from $\varphi$ definition?

Comment: Well, you've proved that $\varphi$ preserves multiplicative identity. There are multiple properties to check for ring homomorphism and this is just one of them. If you're already aware of the others then yes you're good

Comment: Yeah I proved the other two properties.